# Odd wiring at switch. Please help

Tags: wiring, switch, ceiling-fan, light

I plan to run a ceiling fan/light to this switch which is already connected to an outlet. Can you explain this wiring and if it is safe? I don't understand how or why there is a black wire sitting alone or why the white (neutral) is attached to the ground wires. The hot is going into the connector, which is looped to switch, and also contains the wire (white) that supplies power throughout the rest of the room. Help please?

[image]

Comment: wow, that looks messed up .... the neutral should not be connected to the ground .... maybe a call to an electrician is in order

Comment: Can you post clearer photos of the insides of this switch box, as well as photos of the inside of the receptacle box?